# convert compiled exe to base64 and run it from memory does not work

Tags: string, vb.net, memory, base64, byte

I write this code and compile it to .exe:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    MyBase.ShowInTaskbar = False
    MyBase.Opacity = 0

    MessageBox.Show("test", "test")

    MyBase.Close()

End Sub
```

then I convert compiled .exe to base64 code and i wrote this code to run it :

```
Public Class Form1

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    MyBase.ShowInTaskbar = False
    MyBase.Opacity = 0

    Dim qassam As String = "8AALgAAAAAAAAAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA"
    Dim lena As Byte() = Convert.FromBase64String(qassam)

    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Load(lena).EntryPoint.Invoke(Nothing, Nothing)

End Sub
```

8AALgAAAAAAAAAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA = compiled msgbox.exe from step 1 (converted to base64)

the code does not give me any error just not running

Comment: "doesn't work" isn't a very good description of your problem. We need to know any error messages and what is/what isn't happening.

Comment: edit done .....

Comment: @QassamMahmoud how is that a Base64 string from your compiled exe? It's far too short for a program like that. Also, if you set your program to run in 32 bit mode (an option is available in the top of VS), your form will show you your error on load. Also, try putting it in a button and see where you go from there. (Load)

Comment: @AlexM. is right. That is far too little to be a Base64-encoded application. When I created a completely new WinForms app and encoded it to Base64 it was over 27000 characters long.

Comment: @QassamMahmoud just make a real exe file that works, then open the file in a **hex editor** (download a free one), now copy the all bytes (hex values like FB A3 09 etc) and paste into base64 converter. that will give you B64 string of same exe bytes. Now use that B64 string in your code as `Dim qassam As String =` etc etc.

Comment: @VC.One not working man i strill get this error : The program '[6572] WindowsApplication13.vshost.exe' has exited with code -1073741819 (0xc0000005) 'Access violation'.